# After app is submitted to Review in Appstore it got the "Invalid Binary" state

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

I developed application for IOS, which contains application itself, iMessage extension and widget. We tested it thoroughly through TestFlight and I submitted it to Appstore.

Status is changed to "Waiting for Review", but one minute later - to "Invalid Binary".
Well, something is wrong. But when I got mail from server, there are NO explanation there, what is actually wrong. I am and my team made 22 (twenty two) attempts to blindly suggest what can be wrong, but no way - result is the same.

In short:

- I build my application and archive.it.
- I run «Validate» in Organizer window. checks passed.
- I upload it to Appstore. I got message, «Processing Complete».
- I add testers to Testflight, they got invite and can test application. It works like expected.
- I add build to Appstore record and submit to review.
- Application is switched to state «Waiting for Review»
- One minute later I receive email - «Invalid binary».  And no explanation/clarification why it is in this state.

I asked Apple support, and now I have "collection from 4 case IDs. All girls/boys replies me with "There something wrong in your binary, check the mail and make fix".  After I am sharing text with mail, they just ignore my mails.

So the question is:

- How to get info, what is wrong with application, if it passed all tests in XCode, TestFlight and became "Invalid" only one minute later after it is changed to "Waiting for Review" state - it means that it passes check on submitting as well.

+++ Here the full text of message +++

*Dear ...

The status of your app has changed to Invalid Binary.

App Name: ...

App Version Number: 1.0

App SKU: ....

App Apple ID: ....

To make changes to this app, go to your apps's page in My Apps in App Store Connect.
If you have any questions, contact us.

Best regards,

The App Store Team*

+++ +++ +++

Regards,
Vladimir

Comment: is that the very first submission of your app? have you tried to re-archive it with a new build number then re-submit?

Comment: Yes, this operation was repeated 22 times with various options, we removed iMessage and widget, we switched off modes with http request, situation the same. We removed app from appstore and create it again with new Bundle ID. All the same.